# Should config files added by NuGet package be in source control?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

We have a custom NuGet package which contains a DLL and a config file. We make use of NuGet package restore so our packages are not commit in to Perforce. When the package is installed to the solution it adds a reference to the DLL and the config file is included in the root of the project. Both of these are desirable, but should the config file be checked in to source control?

Our CI environment breaks when the file is not checked in, but the package has been downloaded correctly. It looks like this is the correct NuGet behaviour, but I'm not sure what the suggested best practice it is with regards to content files and how they should be treated in version control. Do all *content* files added from packages need to be checked in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet package restore will only restore files into the packages directory.

Files that are copied into your project when installing a NuGet package should be checked into source control since they will not be restored.